# Weird URLs in Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress

Looking at our Excluded by ‘noindex’ tag in the Google Search console we have tens of thousands of these URLs that look like this.

`/page/2/?s=Xổ+số+thể+thao+Xổ+số+kiến+thiết+bóng+đá+5+lần+bao+nhiêu+tiền【Mở+Link∶33k1.com】Nhà+điều+h`

Is there a way to get these removed or have not being added to the search console? It is throwing off our numbers and burying any actual issues we might be having.

These are showing up in the (Excluded by ‘noindex’ tag), if I go to the URL it comes up with our search page.

Comment: Do these links arise from your site or from external links ?

Comment: These appear to be links to the site and not in the site but they show up in the search console.

Comment: What do these url return ?  Do they return a valid page or do they return a 404 etc ?  Please update the question with clarifications.